# How to write the Lagrangian of a cyclic tri-atomic molecule?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I'm familiar with Lagrangian of a $\bf{linear}$ tri-atomic molecule moving only on 1-dimension.[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkJlj.png)

The kinetic energy is written as
$$
T = \frac{1}{2}(m\dot{x}_{1}^{2} + M\dot{x}_{2}^{2} + m\dot{x}_{3}^{2} )
$$
Potential energy
$$
U = \frac{1}{2}(k(x_{2} - x_{1})^{2} +k(x_{3} - x_{2})^{2})
$$
Then the Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L}=T-U$. Suppose now if we have a cyclic molecule like Ozone [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXzx2.png). How do you write the Lagrangian for this? I'm confused in differentiating between the linear and cyclic motion

Comment: $T = \frac12 \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 m_i x_i^2$ and $U = \frac12 \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 k(x_i - x_{i+1})^2$ where $x_4$ is an alias of $x_1$. When dealing with stuff which are "cyclic" in nature, one possible approach is extend the indexing of variables by periodicity.

Comment: The motion is not cyclic. The molecule is. For the linear molecule you ignore the interaction between the atoms not directly connected (there is no $x_1-x_3$ term in the potential energy). For the ozone molecule all three pair of atoms have the same $k$ in the interaction term. Also note that you need at least a 2Ddescription of the problem.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks! Would be possible for you to show your answer in terms of kinetic and potential energy?